# Вычисление процентов sql

Tags: sql

Не судите строго, я только начинаю.
Нужна помощь, чтобы посмотреть, на сколько % был выполнен план.

чтобы это вычислить, добавляю эту строку в запрос,

```
count(t.pcode) / d.doctcode_reg * 100 as result
```

но походу что-то путаю или же нужно переводить
в другой тип.
Подскажите, как будет правильно.

Сам запрос этот:

```
select d.dname "ФИО"
      ,count(t.pcode) "Кол-во приемов"
      ,d.doctcode_reg "План"

from treat t
    ,doctor d

where t.dcode = d.dcode
  and d.doctcode_reg is not null
  and t.treatdate between
      ('01.06.2020 00:00')
  and ('30.06.2020 23:59')

group by d.dname
        ,d.doctcode_reg
```

```
pcode = bigint
doctcode_reg = varchar
```

Спасибо заранее!

Comment: А почему doctcode_reg это varchar, в каком виде и что там лежит ? И какой конкретно диалект SQL (СУБД) используется ?

Comment: Столбец doctcode_reg не был изначально предназначен для вычисления этих данных. Из-за того, что нам не хватило лишних пунктов, чтобы добавить туда это значение, хотим использовать это поле. Но пока только тестируем.
База на FireBird)

Comment: А что происходит при выполнении вашего запроса ? в принципе то он нормально выглядит, а если что то не то с конвертацией типа БД же должна давать ошибку и по коду/тексту этой ошибки будет гораздо понятнее что может быть не так

Comment: При выполнении запроса вот такая ошибка:
```Unsuccessful execution caused by a system error that precludes successful execution of subsequent statements.
Dynamic SQL Error.
expression evaluation not supported.
Strings cannot be divided in dialect 3.
```

Comment: в первой же ссылке в гугле с вашим текстом ошибки говорят, что надо явно делать `cast(d.doctcode_reg as float)` в вашем случае возможно int. Надо всегда начинать именно с текста ошибок, что бы люди не гадали на кофейной гуще что же у вас за БД и что с ней не так

Comment: Спасибо большое, получилось!
count(cast(t.pcode as float)) / cast(d.doctcode_reg as float) * 100 AS result - итоговая строка